# Android Emulator keeps quitting when taking screenshots

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

I can't recall if I have ever tinkered with the settings of Android Emulator, but I've been testing my app on an Android Emulator using Android Studio, and every time I take a screenshot, it crashes.

I tried deleting, and wiping, and creating a new Emulator. None of it works. I tried also to take a screenshot without running my app, with a fresh emulator, and the same problem occurs. It just crashes whenever I try to take a picture.

Android Studio reports this error:

> Blockquote
> WARNING | unexpected system image feature string, emulator might not function correctly, please try updating the emulator. WARNING | cannot add library /Users/sbenati/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed INFO | configAndStartRenderer: setting vsync to 60 hz INFO | added library /Users/sbenati/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib WARNING | cannot add library /Users/sbenati/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed INFO | added library /Users/sbenati/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib INFO | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local INFO | Advertising in: /Users/sbenati/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/avd/running/pid_935.ini

My machine is a Mac with 32GB of RAM and i7 CPU, so I can't imaging this an issue with system performance.

If no one has any suggestions, I will have to just reinstall everything. Thanks for the tips everyone.

**Edit:**

I ran this on a new Mac mini I recently acquired, and got this really helpful message. I traced it down to a suggested solution about switching off Vulcan, but it did not work for me.

[image]

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69654531/edit) your post to include which PC/Mac (probably Mac as I see 'darwin' string) with specs (CPU/RAM/etc.) along with OS version you are using.

Comment: Thank you @MorrisonChang. It's a Mac alright, and the machine runs at more than high-end specs with i7-7700K and 32GB of RAM. OS is Catalina.

Comment: Have you tried to clean or reset the emulator?

Comment: And I tried to update my Mac on High Sierra and got this issue: [MacOS HAXM Installer Broken](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197769309) If you still have a 'working 'emulator you might want to update with what version of SDK tools & emulator/HAXM you are using.

Comment: @Ibxx yes I did. I think I will just remove everything and reinstall

Comment: I am facing same issue and it occured when I updated emlator to version 30.9.5. Before that there were no crashes when taking screenshots. Macbook 2019 / 8gb / 256 / Big Sur 11.6.

Comment: This is a known issue on the Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203692316

Comment: Have this problem too on Mac, but it works fine on Windows, same version of Android Emulator.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203692316) and has been fixed in Android Emulator 31.1.1.

This version currently isn't marked as stable yet. A workaround:

- Switch to the Canary channel in Android Studio
- Update the emulator
- Switch back to stable

[image: AS]

Update emulator:

[image: AS]

Comment: worked for me also.

Answer (score 12):

I've been having the same problem (I'm on macOS Monterey), each time I try to take a screenshot the emulator crashes.

Sadly I haven't found a direct solution to this problem, that is a solution fixing the issue in the simulator. But I have learned that it is possible to take screenshots of the app from inside Android Studio, using Logcat.

Essentially, when you're running your app, if you go to the Logcat tab, there is a screenshot option which does seem to work without crashing. I've added a link to developer.android.com which explains how to do it.

Even thought this doesn't exactly fix the problem I hope it helps!

[Take a screenshot (through android studio)](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-screenshot)

**Edit:**

I am happy to report that after a recent update for the emulator released by the developers, the issue no longer exists for me! The screenshot button has now started working again.

So if someone has the issue, I believe it can now be fixed by just updating your emulator to the latest version available.

Comment: That helped me. Its good to know.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked for me. Thank you.