# Screen Capture on Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to screenshot on an Android Studio Emulator Pixel 4 XL API 30,
but whenever I try to take one, the Emulator ends itself.
And then I get the message "Lost connection to Device".
Could anyone tell me if there is a way to solve this problem?

__

I tried changing the saved folder, and restarting the emulator

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69941260/7948109)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to reproduce the error.

But try the obvious: a cold boot of the emulator, and if all else fails, create a whole new emulated device. I frequently encounter weird bugs in the emulator that I solve with a hard reset.

This may be of use to you as well:
[Taking screenshot on Emulator from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983351/taking-screenshot-on-emulator-from-android-studio)